# Mutually Inclusive Inheritance with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, inheritance

I have a scenario where I need to implement Mutually Inclusive Inheritance and I am using Entity Framework Code First as ORM. I have an abstract User class, Customer and Employee classes which are inherited from User. I have currently implemented table-per-type to model inheritance in SQL database.

Now, whenever I try to fetch both of the entities with a single db context object it gives me this exception

> All objects in the EntitySet 'Context.Users' must have unique primary
>   keys. However, an instance of type 'Employee' and an instance of type
>   'Customer' both have the same primary key value,
>   'EntitySet=Users;Id=153'

I do understand the reason why this is causing issue, but I can't find any workaround for it.

The solution that might work is that I would create a separate Primary Key for Customer and Employee and keep UserAccountId as Foreign Key, but I can't find a way to configure it through Entity Framework.

Following is a dummy code for my scenario

```
public abstract class UserAccount
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : UserAccount
{

}

public class Customer : UserAccount
{

}

public class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable(nameof(Customer));
    }
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable(nameof(Employee));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Are you adding data manually to db, because EF won't allow to add data in both Employee and Customer table for a user entry.

Comment: No, I am using entity framework to insert the data too, and the error I am facing is while fetching and not while adding data. Thanks

Comment: Maybe show us the code for that?

Comment: Do you have a single `DbSet` for these entities? Also, please show how you are adding the data.

Comment: I have a DbSet for each of the types, but I am using the same DbContext to fetch

Comment: I don't think the issue is with the above code - the error shows that `Employee` and `Customer` both have the same `primary key` _153_. So this would mean that you have two `Users` with the same `Id` please check the two tables to see if you have records for `Id` _153_ in both `Customer` and `Employee`. If there is you will need to delete one.

Comment: I know that the error is coming because they both have Id 153 and its intended to be like that because the User Account 153 is Customer and Employee both. I want the inheritance to be mutually inclusive, i.e. a User can be an Employee and Customer both at the same time.

Comment: You cannot do that with you current set up. In your current design `Customer` and `Employee` are not related in that way. You can either change the inheritance if all `Customers` are also `Employees` or visa-versa. Or create two `User` entries one for the `Employee` data and one for the `Customer` data and then have a foreign key from `Customer` and `Employee`

Comment: Implementing any of the suggestions would defeat the whole point of inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not right. When using ORM try to think in terms of Objects. A User cannot be converted have two concrete type when you fetch the data.

You need to look at the problem from a different perspective and design your object relation accordingly. You need to use composition here and not inheritance.

Comment: Your ans is too harsh for him :D

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. But I had in mind that if I could configure EF to have a different primary key in Customer and Employee rather than making UserAccount.Id primary key and foreign key, then I might get a work around of this problem. Can you think of anyway to configure it like this. and of course composition is my fallback approach if i don't find any good solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment `User` can have both a `Customer` and `Employee` entry with the same `primary key`. So when you tell Entity Framework to select all `Users` you are getting a clash on the `User.Id` column.

I presume that you want to have one `User` entry per `Customer` and `Employee`.

You could do this by removing the inheritance.

#### Example

```
public class UserAccount
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
    public Customer Customer {get;set;}
}

public class Employee 
{
    public User User {get;set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public User User {get;set;}
}
```